# Fatal error: Call to a member function setQuote() on boolean in /home/thetiresquire/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php on line 745

Tags: function, call, member

Please help me to resolve the error am getting on home page.

```
MY CART :
    0 item(s) - 
    Fatal error: Call to a member function setQuote() on boolean in /home/thetiresquire/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php on line 745
```

Here is the code where it is pointing to is

```
 public function getItemsCollection($useCache = true)
        {
            if ($this->hasItemsCollection()) {
                return $this->getData('items_collection');
            }
            if (is_null($this->_items)) {
                $this->_items = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection();
                $this->_items->setQuote($this);
            }
            return $this->_items;
    }
```

The  error is pointing to line   `$this->_items->setQuote($this);` 
I have cleared the cache and flushed the cache from `admin`

Please help am new to magento.

Thanks,
Shabana